# Populate the checkbox items as per the category selected - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a two tables for category and its items. I need to select a category and then show respective items in a form. How can I do that?

Category model

```
class SizeCategory extends Model
{
    public function size() {
        return $this-> hasMany(Size::class);
    }    
}
```

Items model

```
class Size extends Model
{
    public function sizeCategory() {
        return $this->belongsTo(SizeCategory::class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function create() {
    $sizeCategory = SizeCategory::all();
    return view('products.create', [
        'sizeCategories' => $sizeCategory,
    ]);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="size_category_id" id="" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Select Size Category</option>
            @foreach ($sizeCategories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->size_category_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

//how to populate items(sizes) of above selected category here without calling a server again?

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="sizeId">
    <div class="form-group row">
        @foreach ($sizeCategories->find(1)->size as $size)
        <div class="d-inline-block mt-2 ml-2">
            <label class="checkbox-container">
                <input type="checkbox" name="available_size_id[]" value="{{$size->id}}">
                {{$size->size_name}}
                <span class="checkbox-circle"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

One way to do it is get the items of the category through server after selecting the category (ajax) but I want to load all categories and respective items of each category when the form loads and after selecting the category, simply populate its items. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can pass to JS all sizes when you load the page. And when you select a category, filter the array by categories and reload your select.

Comment: ok I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your controller eager load the relation first:

```
public function create() {
    $sizeCategory = SizeCategory::with('size')->get();
    return view('products.create', [
        'sizeCategories' => $sizeCategory,
    ]);
}
```

in your blade than after selecting category

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="sizeId">
<div class="form-group row">
    @foreach ($sizeCategories->size as $size)
    <div class="d-inline-block mt-2 ml-2">
        <label class="checkbox-container">
            <input type="checkbox" name="available_size_id[]" value="{{$size->id}}">
            {{$size->size_name}}
            <span class="checkbox-circle"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: HI, it gives err: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all(). if use get() instead of all() it works but how to show the items of selected catehory only? It will dispaly all the sub items.